# PloneFormGen Fixed Point Field Internationalization - Swap comma and decimal

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I am trying to find a way to change the format of the decimal or fixed point field in PFG to accept comma as decimal point, and a decimal as the comma separator. This is for a Brazilian site so we are trying to match their formatting. I found [this post on the Plone-Users mailing list](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/PFG-and-comma-as-decimal-point-indicator-td3452737.html), which led me to believe setting the site language to Portuguese would fix it but the site's language was already set to Portuguese. There wasn't really a resolution found on that page, and I am still having issues.

- Plone 4.3.2
- PloneFormGen 1.7.14

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure, but think PFG formatting is based on Archetypes, and only the changelog for https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Archetypes/1.9.8 has comma as decimal separator. And that's definitely after Plone 4.3.2 was released.

You might try on a development copy if updating (pinning) Archetypes to that newer version helps.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't catch that. I'll try that next. Thanks!